# For i = 2 to thisworkbook.worksheets.count through all the worksheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, worksheet

Can anyone help me out? I am trying to make my code loop through all the worksheets in a workbook. It does perfectly for the one worksheet, but I am struggling to make it loop through all the worksheets

```
    Sub stringcheck()

Dim MainString As String
Dim SubString As String
Dim Lastrow As Long, Lcount As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

SubString = "All Grps"

Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SalesChannelName").Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 3 To Lastrow
    MainString = Range("B" & i)
        If InStr(MainString, SubString) <> 0 Then
            Rows(Range("A" & i).Row + 1 & ":" & Range("A" & i).Row + 2).Insert
        End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may give this a try...

```
Sub stringcheck()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MainString As String
    Dim SubString As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Lcount As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SubString = "All Grps"

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Lastrow To 3 Step -1
            MainString = ws.Range("B" & i)
            If InStr(MainString, SubString) <> 0 Then
                ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. that was a very creative manner in which to change the code and make it loop through all pages :)

Comment: @KokoEtokebe You're welcome! If that takes care of your original question, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

To loop you code through all worksheets, please use code below.

```
Sub stringcheck()

Dim MainString As String
Dim SubString As String
Dim Lastrow As Long, Lcount As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate
SubString = "All Grps"

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 3 To Lastrow
    MainString = Range("B" & i)
        If InStr(MainString, SubString) <> 0 Then
            Rows(Range("A" & i).Row + 1 & ":" & Range("A" & i).Row + 2).Insert
        End If
Next i
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, but what about the lastrow = thisworkbook.worksheets("Saleschannelname").range("A30000").end(xlup).row which is specifying the last cell in another worksheet. I reckon that willc cause an error